# How does the Gmail app achieve it's flat view hierarchy?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm attempting to optimize my listitems, when I go into my developer options and turn on "Show Layout Bounds" I noticed that the Gmail app has a completely flat view hierarchy? How is this black magic achieved?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Custom views, most likely.

Comment: I'd like to hear about this black magic too

Comment: Does that mean they're drawing the entire listitem inside the onDraw method for a custom view? For something like the star or the user images how would that be achieved? Also in the gmail app, clicking the avatar creates a flip effect, are they drawing that animation too? Would the star image require a custom Path? This is complete magic to me.

Comment: Have a look at [Custom ViewGroups](https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/custom-viewgroups/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're likely overriding onDraw and drawing directly to the canvas instead of adding views as children.

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, I might be wrong on a few details, but they are using a custom view. A widget, if you want.

Practically, you have a class that extends something, most likely a View, a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout, than you programmatically add the stuff you need in there and make sure you have methods to acces the stuff from outside, so that when you create a new "thingy", you will be able to give it whatever text or images you want.

In your case, what I would do is a widget that extends LinearLayout and I would add there the image, 3 textViews (name, subject, actual mail) and one more TextView for the date. If you want the star too, that would be one more thing added, an ImageView. You move them around whatever way you want, and that's pretty much it.

If you want some code for that, let me know, I'll give you some more details if you really need.

Comment: But wouldn't adding the image and 3 textviews still add items to the view hierarchy? I don't understand why those views don't have a layoutbound. I'm guessing the text must be done with a canvas.drawText() method, I just don't understand how they can have a custom ondraw method which also animates the avatars? I'll try out your suggestion to see if that actualy removes the layoutbounds.

Comment: Well, I am not sure about this ,you wanna double check this, but I am pretty sure the hierarchy sees it as one thing.For example if you extend your class as a LinearLayout ,it sees it as a LinearLayout.

Comment: Is it possible it's a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout with the topmost (z-order) view encompassing the full height/width? Maybe this topmost view ignores or passes on click events in order to handle the "star" click? Just a wild guess.

Comment: I kind of doubt it to be honest.Specially the RelativeLayout part.

Comment: @android_student let me know when you try it and out and see if it removes the layoutbounds

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same flat UI using Litho. Litho uses a recycler view underneath. Unlike a recycler view,  which only reuses the views in the view pool using viewholders, Litho reuses every ui element(Imageview, textview etc..).

https://fblitho.com/static/videos/incremental_recycling.mp4

Advantages:

- Flat UI.
- Asynchronous layout inflation. (View measurement is offloaded to the background thread)
- Incremental mount. (Only visible views are rendered by default)

Disadvantages:

- No visual layout editor.
- The learning curve to get started.

Once you implement this in your project, you can see the results for yourself.